# MemcachedError: error 31 A TIMEOUT OCCURRED'

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, memcached, django-1.5, pylibmc

I have a live server instance running on `AWS`,I took the `AMI` of current  running instance and with that I created an another instance and I configured all the settings and the web server is `nginx` but when I enter my IP address I get memcached error.

```
  Unable to reach Sentry log server: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> (url: http://sentry.openlabs.co.in/api/32/store/)
 Failed to submit message: u'MemcachedError: error 31 from memcached_get(:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_): A TIMEOUT OCCURRED'
```

This is my settings.py

```
 CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': 'pursuite.vbzolj.cfg.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211',
    }
 }
```

In live server its working fine. Don't know why its not working in staging.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that your server is not able to send requests to your Memcached instance.

Check that your instances are part of the same security group and enable inbound traffic for Memcached.

To enable inbound traffic for Memcached:

1. Open your EC2 Management Console
2. Go in *Security Groups* under *NETWORK & SECURITY*
3. Select the security group that you're using for your server and your Memcached instance.
4. Open the *Inbound* tab, and add a *Custom TPC Rule* for enabling inbound traffic from your group ID and port 11211